# Azure to on premises web services

Tags: azure

Can anybody tell me how to connect a web app running on azure to existing web services (.ASMX) on premises?

We do not have the source for the services they are exposed by third party applications and we do not want to open them up to public access.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Azure's [Service Bus Relay Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/) might be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

There might be three options based on your scenario. But I personally prefer the third one.

1. If you used azure cloud service (web role, worker role), you can use Windows Azure Connect. It builds an IP-sec communication between the azure machine and your local machine. Then you can connect to your local service through the its IPv6 address.
2. If you used azure virtual machine to host your azure project you can use Virtual Network. It's more powerful than the Windows Azure Connect.
3. You can use Windows Azure Service Bus Relay. It can open your local service to the cloud regardless how your azure project is hosted. But since it's only support WCF of Service Relay, and since you cannot change codes and config of your service, you might need some more works. Maybe you can create a small WCF on your local machine as a proxy, register it to Service Bus Relay, and pass all request/response to your local service.